# Angular - Callback from Service after Component is destroyed

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have some little questions about Angular Components and the OnDestroy lifecycle hook.

I have an Angular Service and an Angular Component. From the component I am calling a function inside the service. Because the function can't return a result directly, I am using a callback to get the result. I pass the callback as arrow function inside the component.

I have noticed that if I execute the function which calls the function inside the service, and then - before the callback gets called - route to another component so the current one gets destroyed, the callback still gets executed after the component itself (which contains the callback as arrow function) was destroyed.

Now to my questions:

How does that work under the hood? Is Angular destroying only the view(template) and waits until the callback was called and then destroys the rest(code)?

Or is it intended that ngOnDestroy only destroys the view and the rest is handled by garbage collection/the browser itself?

Is there any way that I can check if the component still exists and wasn't destroyed and only then call the callback?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't the service return a direct result? is it returning a promise or other asyncronous result? Maybe in this case you can have a true false flag in your controller that is updated on finish of callback, allowing navigation if true

Comment: Angular doesn't "destroy code", ever. `ngOnDestroy` is a method called when Angular destroys the DOM node created by that component. Function calls are still in browser stack and will still be called.

Comment: @Dale Sorry :) The function in the service reads the entries of a passed directory and returns an array of the files inside the directory (I am using the entries API).

Comment: @ritaj Thanks for clarifying that. So the browser will carbage collect the rest of the component instance (code etc.) when it is no longer needed or how does this work?

Comment: Well, the browser collects object instances when there are no more references to the object. Angular will dereference component instance when `onDestroy` happens. Functions called before component destruction will still be on the stack and so the component will not yet be collected.

Comment: So just for me to understand: Lets say, I call the function inside the service, and before this function finishes, I navigate to another route in my app, so the component gets destroyed (so the DOM node is destroyed). Then the function finishes and fires the callback inside the components model/"code". After that, all references to the object are gone, so the browser now garbage collects it? In the time between DOM node destruction and the execution of the callback the object remains and after that it gets destroyed? Do I understand this correctly or am I on the "wrong way"?

Answer (score 1):

Inside service, you can maintain a status flag will set tp true, if the component is destroy. You can set the service flag to true on component ngOnDestroy. When callback is executing you can proceed execution only when flag is false.

As per the official angular docs, A ondestroy lifecycle hook that is called when a directive, pipe, component or service is destroyed. Use for any custom cleanup that needs to occur when the instance is destroyed.